# Add a restored Java project to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Suppose I extracted a Java project from a `tar` archive.  How do I add it to Eclipse (Indigo)?

In the past when I have had to so something like this, I simply created a new Eclipse project with the same name and manually copied all the .java files into the proper folder down at `workspace/projectName/src/topDomain/companyDomain/packageName`.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File - Import... - Existing project into workspace.

This supposes that the tar archive contains the whole project, including the .project and .classpath files.

If it doesn't, then either make a new project where you want, and copy the source files, or create a project and specify that its location must be the directory containing the sources folder that you extracted from the tar.

Comment: It's actually `File/Import/General/Existing`.